# How is this variable of type pointer to pointer

Tags: c, struct, dereference, pointer-to-pointer

```
struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *link;
};

struct node *addnode(struct node **head);

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    addnode(&head);

    return 0;
}


struct node *addnode(struct node **ptrTohead)
{
       if (*ptrTohead == NULL)
       {
          struct node *newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
          *ptrTohead = newNode;
       }

}
```

i am making a linked list implementation in C and came across this code: what i do not understand is how `&head` is of type `struct node **` after all `*head` is a pointer that stores an address, and `&head` gets the address of the head variable. So how is that a pointer to pointer?

This is how i imagine it:

```
//                head ----> |___2______| 
/memory address/  100           200
// &head is 100 and is of type struct node *
```

Comment: `head` is a `struct node*` and taking the address of `head` gets you the pointer to a `struct node*` which is a `struct node**` (there must be a duplicate to this?)

Comment: You just described how you have a pointer, and you took a pointer to it. How is that not a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: "`*head` is a pointer" ... No, `head` is a pointer. `*head` dereferences that pointer (and is of type `struct node`).  The address of a pointer is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: so basically taking the address of ```head```, gives the address of a pointer (```head```) and ```head``` points to something hence joining these two ideas together means it is a struct node**? am i thinking of this correctly its so confusing lol

Comment: Yes.  For any type `T`, pointer to `T` is `T*`.  pointer to `T*` is `T**`.

Comment: The `*` has a different meaning, depending on where it is written. In a declaration, it means "pointer". However, outside a declaration, it is the dereference operator, which is used to dereference pointers.

Comment: The name reuse of `head` between the prototype and `main` probably didn't do you any favors. Hyper focus on the types.

Comment: but what i dont get is that *head is a pointer that stores a address, right? a pointer to pointer is essentially a pointer variable that holds the address of another pointer variable. All *head does is store the address of a struct NOT another pointer. so if that is the case &head should give us the address of the pointer known as head, so how on earth is this a pointer to a pointer then?

Comment: As has been stated several times in the comments, "\*head is a pointer that stores a address" is *not* correct.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate this simple demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;
    
    int *p = &x;

    printf( "The variable x stores the value %d\n", x );
    printf( "Its address is %p\n", ( void * )&x );
    
    printf( "\nThe pointer p stores the address of the variable x %p\n", 
            ( void * )p );
    printf( "Dereferencing the pointer p we will get x equal to %d\n" , *p );
    printf( "The address of the pointer p itself is %p\n", ( void * )&p );
    
    int **pp = &p;
    
    printf( "\nThe pointer pp stores the address of the pointer p %p\n", 
            ( void * )pp );
    printf( "Dereferencing the pointer pp we will get the address stored in p %p\n",
            ( void * )*pp );
    printf( "Dereferencing the pointer pp two times "
            "we will get  x equal to %d\n", **pp );

    int y = 20;
    
    printf( "\nBecause dereferencing the pointer pp\n"
            "we have a direct access to the value stored in p\n"
            "we can change the value of p\n" );

    *pp = &y;           

    printf( "\nNow the pointer p stores the address of the variable y %p\n", 
            ( void * )p );
    printf( "Dereferencing the pointer p we will get y equal to %d\n" , *p );
    printf( "The address of the pointer p itself was not changed %p\n", ( void * )&p );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
The variable x stores the value 10
Its address is 0x7fffd5f6de90

The pointer p stores the address of the variable x 0x7fffd5f6de90
Dereferencing the pointer p we will get x equal to 10
The address of the pointer p itself is 0x7fffd5f6de98

The pointer pp stores the address of the pointer p 0x7fffd5f6de98
Dereferencing the pointer pp we will get the address stored in p 0x7fffd5f6de90
Dereferencing the pointer pp two times we will get  x equal to 10

Because dereferencing the pointer pp
we have a direct access to the value stored in p
we can change the value of p

Now the pointer p stores the address of the variable y 0x7fffd5f6de94
Dereferencing the pointer p we will get y equal to 20
The address of the pointer p itself was not changed 0x7fffd5f6de98
```

That is the variables `p` and `pp` are both pointers. The difference is that the pointer `p` points to an object of the type `int` (to the variable `x` or `y`) while the pointer `pp` points to the variable `p` that has the type `int *`. Dereferencing any of these pointers you will get a direct access to the pointed object and can change it (if it is not a constant object).

Comment: thanks that was helpful but i still dont get why &head is a pointer to pointer could you edit your answer and answer that please

Comment: @programmerc3981143 Because head is itself a pointer struct node *head = NULL; Now investigate the program shown in my answer one more.

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, `head` is a pointer to struct node.  The expression `&head` is the address of a pointer to struct node.
`ptrTohead` is the formal parameter of the function `addnode` and is a pointer to pointer to struct node.  The value of `&head` can be assigned to `ptrTohead` because it is the address of a pointer to struct node, and the address of a pointer to struct node is an appropriate value with which to initialize a pointer to pointer to struct node.

Note that `&head` is *not* a pointer to pointer to struct node.  It is the address of a pointer to struct node.  Also note that `*head` is not a pointer.  `*head` is a struct node, while `head` is a pointer to struct node.

Comment: if ```&head``` isnt a pointer to pointer why does it have type ```struct node **```, is it because each level of the expression ```&head``` has a seperate value and putting them together gives ```struct node**```? by *level* i mean the depth of the addresses in this expression. So ```&head``` gives the address of the pointer which is 1 level of type ```struct node *```, then de-referencing this gives another address of type ```struct node*```. Those two types added together give ```struct node**```. Well thats how i think of it at least how correct is this @WilliamPursell

Comment: This is probably semantic quibbling.  The expression `&head` evaluates to the address of a pointer to struct node.  A variable of type `struct node **` can be assigned a value which is the address of a pointer to struct node.

Comment: Ah ok i see but would the way i think of it suffice or is this incorrect?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "depth of the addresses".  I find it easier to always think of `T *h` meaning that h is a pointer to T.  So `&h` is the address of a pointer to T.  Whether `T` is an `int` or a `struct foo ***` is irrelevant.